# Does anyone know of a good source on French folk customs?

Tags: middle-ages, france, everyday-life

I have been looking into French culture and was wondering if anyone knows of a book or collection of documents, etc... That contain prayers, customs, etc... That the French practiced. Kinda like a French version of the Carmina Gadelica. Does anyone know if something like this exists or a comparable source? (Middle Ages)

Comment: The realities on the ground in the various corners of France were quite different between the fall of Rome and the time when France had more or less its current borders. Can I suggest that you specify the part of France you're interested in if applicable?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Brittiany or Savoie would be the most preferable but I'm Im not very picky so any region helps.

Comment: Right, so you're not really looking for France here, but rather [Brittany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Brittany#Middle_Ages) and [Savoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoy#History).